# Hover on element in one Div that changes the background image of another Div CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change a `div`'s background image when hovering over other elements on the page. For example, in my project I have two `div`'s, if I hover the element with the content "nature", then it will change the `show` `div`'s background image.

My code is as follows:

**CSS:**

```
  .divOne #one:hover ~ .show{ background-image: url(nature.jpg); }  
  .divOne two:hover ~ .show{ background-image: url(bird.jpg); }            
  #show{
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;           
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divOne">
   <a id="one" href="#"> nature </a>
   <a id="two" href="#"> bird </a>
</div>

<div class="show"></div>
```

Comment: `#one` and `#two` are not previous siblings of `#show` (this is what `~` stands for). Put `#show` inside `#divOne` after the links  in order to work

Comment: Sorry. it must be two different div. please ignore the css code. Tell me what i need to change both css and html code to acheive my goal. i know it will work when i put the second div indise the first div. but i should be two different div.

Comment: With the given markup, this effect is not possible in pure css

Comment: Why don't you make use of `Javascript` or `jQuery`?

Comment: i have a solution  with jQuery do you need

Comment: yeah okay. shall you give the solution pls.

Comment: A typo on your code makes it impossible to work: your image div have the class 'show' and do not have an id. So it shall be '.show' instead of '#show' (when setting its size). Your "canvas div" current height/width is equal to zero.

Comment: As seen here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkjkoj2j/) (from comments in an answer below), the ~target div can be in a different container, not the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this:

```js
$(".divOne").find("#one").hover(function(){
 $(".show").css("background","green");
});
$(".divOne").find("#two").hover(function(){
 $(".show").css("background","blue");
});
$(".divOne #one, .divOne #two").mouseleave(function(){
$(".show").css("background","none");
});
```

```html
<div class="divOne">
  <a id="one" href="#"> nature </a><br/>
  <a id="two" href="#"> bird </a>
</div>

<div class="show"> 
Test Background
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a different example, but related to you.
    
    
    #red
    {
    background-color:red;
    }
    #green
    {
    background-color:green;
    }
    #red:hover~#green
    {
    color: orange;
    }
    
    
    
    red
    
    
    green

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you'd look at using JS / jQuery in your comments, you could use jQuery's `toggleClass` and bind it to a hover event: https://jsfiddle.net/0pe4mn4o/

**jQuery:**

```
$("#one").hover(function() {
    $(".show").toggleClass("green");
});
$("#two").hover(function() {
    $(".show").toggleClass("red");
});
```

Then with CSS we can style the `.green` / `.red` classes to do what we like when appended to the `.show` div (you can use a `background-image` if you prefer).

**CSS:**

```
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
} 
#show{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}   
.divOne a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divOne">
   <a id="one" href="#"> nature </a>
   <a id="two" href="#"> bird </a>
</div>
<div class="show">SHOW DIV</div>
```